# What is the smallest number of times I can copy the data in order to return the contents of an io.Reader as a string pointer?

Tags: go, pointers, casting

A coworker implemented a function that makes an HTTP call and returns the response body as a string. Simplifying a bit for brevity (no, we're not really ignoring all the errors):

```golang
func getStuff(id string) string {
    response, _ := http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("/some/url/%s", id))
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    return string(body)
}
```

The response is typically fairly large, so I want to avoid unnecessary copying. As I understand it, as written, we are making three copies of the response data:

1. `io.ReadAll` copies the data from the incoming HTTP connection to a byte slice.
2. `string(body)` copies the byte slice into a string.
3. `return` makes a new copy of the string for use in the calling function.

So, first of all, do I understand the current state correctly?

The easy first step is to return a pointer:

```golang
response, _ := http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("/some/url/%s", id))
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
result := string(body)
return &result
```

That avoids the third copy. Cool. But I'm still making two copies of the data, and I'd like to make just one.

I could have him change the return type to `*[]byte`, and then we can just `return &body`. But then all of the callers would need to convert the result to string themselves, and then all I've accomplished is to spread the logic that makes the second copy around to multiple other places instead of keeping it consolidated here.

I could use `strings.Builder` and `io.Copy`:

```golang
builder := new(strings.Builder)
_, _ := io.Copy(buf, response.Body)
result buf.String()
return &result
```

And that might be a tiny bit more efficient (I don't really know; is it?), but I still end up with two copies of the data.

Is it possible to do this with just a single copy of the data?

I think it's not; just wondering if I'm wrong!

Comment: A good strategy in these cases is to benchmark your code to find out which variation performs best

Comment: @blackgreen agreed! I have no experience benchmarking memory usage of Go applications, but would love to learn. Any pointers?

Comment: https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with go's benchmarking tools, but AFAIK (supported by your link), they are for benchmarking run time. I am interested in benchmarking memory usage.

Comment: then you just run `go test` with `-benchmem` option, or call `b.ReportAllocs` in the benchmark code. See also https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Testing_flags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying a string only copies the string header, which contains two words: pointer to the array containing string data, and the length. It does not copy the string contents. Thus, returning a string from a function will not copy the string.

If you are passing that string to something like json unmarshaling, you can return the `[]byte`, or even, the reader from the body, and process it. If you need it as a string, then two-copies is the best you can have: once to read it from the body, and second, to convert it into a string.

Comment: Thank you! Can you point to some documentation somewhere to back up your claims about how strings are copied?

Comment: FWIW: in the majority case for my usage, the entire response body, which is JSON, is being copied into a struct field as a string; we then marshal that struct into JSON. I'm pretty sure that part of the code could be more efficient too, but didn't want to muddy up this question asking about that part.

Comment: Try this, and you'll see: `fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof("a"))`

Comment: Also: https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.18.1#StringHeader